# How to disable ng-test execution during prod ng build

Tags: build, angular-cli

I am pretty new to angular-cli based projects.

I have created my angular-cli project. I am wondering is there a way we can disable/enable ng-test execution during ng build --prod. The reason why i need this is, in my CI-CD env (where  i am building a Prod release), i don't need npm test or any karma related stuff,where as i need them only in my local testing.

I tried the below options in my .angular-cli.json, but it didn't work either.
(a) I tried to comment out test in my .angular-cli.json

```
  // "test": {
  //   "karma": {
  //     // "config": "./karma.conf.js"
  //   }
  // },
```

(b) I tried to comment only the karma section

How can i control over test execution in prod build?

Comment: `ng build` build an application to the dist folder. `ng test` runs the unit tests you have coded. The two don't overlap. It's either one, or the other. If you run `ng build` as a part of you CI/CD process, it will not include unit tests in the output.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's a bit late to answer this but I ran in the same conserns and found this solution :

In your "tsonfig.app.json", you could add this line :

```
"exclude": ["src/test.ts", "**/*.spec.ts"]
```